# How to replace string in files and file and folder names recursively with PowerShell?

Tags: windows-7, powershell

With PowerShell (although other suggestions are welcome), how does one recursively loop a directory/folder and

1. replace text A with B in all files,
2. rename all files so that A is replaced by B, and last
3. rename all folders also so that A is replaced by B?

Comment: So you want one command/function that will replace A with B in file contents, file names, and folder names or are A and B separate in each of those cases?

Comment: "one command/function that will replace A with B in file contents, file names, and folder names" is the case.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With a few requirements refinements, I ended up with this script:

```
$match = "MyAssembly" 
$replacement = Read-Host "Please enter a solution name"

$files = Get-ChildItem $(get-location) -filter *MyAssembly* -Recurse

$files |
    Sort-Object -Descending -Property { $_.FullName } |
    Rename-Item -newname { $_.name -replace $match, $replacement } -force



$files = Get-ChildItem $(get-location) -include *.cs, *.csproj, *.sln -Recurse 

foreach($file in $files) 
{ 
    ((Get-Content $file.fullname) -creplace $match, $replacement) | set-content $file.fullname 
}

read-host -prompt "Done! Press any key to close."
```

Comment: This is awesome.  When people realize what this script will allow you to do, you'll get a lot more upvotes...  thanks.

Comment: I had some folders and namespaces in code files giving me an issue names like NameSpace.TestConsole (folder) and same goes for some of my namespaces, this script then made a lot of empty files called those names instead, so somehow it also creates new files. is there some way to ensure it only replaces and not creates?

Answer (score 3):

I would go with something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem $directory -Recurse |
    Sort-Object -Descending -Property { $_.FullName } |
    ForEach-Object {
        if (!$_.PsIsContainer) {
            ($_|Get-Content) -replace 'A', 'B' | Set-Content $_.FullName
        }
        $_
    } |
    Rename-Item { $_.name -replace 'A', 'B' }
```

The `Sort-Object` is there to ensure that first children (subdirs, files) are listed and then directories after them. (12345)

Comment: And the question is: why? :) As somebody 'around computers' you might know, that "It doesn't work" is as worthy as if you say nothing. Error message is helpful. Otherwise, no need to say "It doesn't work". :)

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but should give you a starting point:

```
$a = 'A';
$b = 'B';
$all = ls -recurse;
$files = = $all | where{ !$_.PSIsContainer );
$files | %{ 
   $c = ( $_ | get-itemcontent -replace $a,$b ); 
   $c | out-file $_;
}
$all | rename-item -newname ( $_.Name -replace $a,$b );
```

Comment: I can tell that is untested, there is no way that would run.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Untested, may be I'm more lucky ;-)

```
$hello = 'hello'
$world = 'world'

$files = ls -recurse | ? {-not $_.PSIsContainer} 

foearch ($file in $files) {
  gc -path $file | % {$_ -replace $hello, $world} | Set-Content $file
  ri -newname ($file.name -replace $hello, $world)
}

ls -recurse | ? {$_.PSIsContainer} | ri -newname ($_.name -replace $hello, $world)
```

To use the same recursion:

```
$hello = 'hello'
$world = 'world'

$everything = ls -recurse 

foearch ($thing in $everything) {
  if ($thing.PSIsContainer -ne $true) {
     gc -path $thing | % {$_ -replace $hello, $world} | Set-Content $thing
  }
  ri -newname ($thing.name -replace $hello, $world)
}
```

Comment: It's little complex, so I would test it as a script.

Answer (score 0):

I needed this for myself and below slightly better version of the script.

I added followings:

1. Support for verbose parameter so you can actually see what changes script has made.
2. Ability to specify folders so you can limit changes.
3. Adding bower.json, txt and md in to include extensions.
4. Search and replace content first, do rename later.
5. Do not replace content if search string is not found (this avoids unnecessary change in modified date).

```
[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true)]
Param()

$match = "MyProject" 
$replacement = Read-Host "Please enter project name"

$searchFolders = @("MyProject.JS", "MyProject.WebApi", ".")
$extensions = @("*.cs", "*.csproj", "*.sln", "bower.json", "*.txt", "*.md")
foreach($searchFolderRelative in $searchFolders)
{
    $searchFolder = join-path (get-location) $searchFolderRelative
    Write-Verbose "Folder: $searchFolder"

    $recurse = $searchFolderRelative -ne "."

    if (test-path $searchFolder)
    {
        $files = Get-ChildItem (join-path $searchFolder "*") -file -include $extensions  -Recurse:$recurse |
                    Where-Object {Select-String -Path $_.FullName $match -SimpleMatch -Quiet}

        foreach($file in $files) 
        { 
            Write-Verbose "Replaced $match in $file"
            ((Get-Content $file.fullname) -creplace $match, $replacement) | set-content $file.fullname 
        }

        $files = Get-ChildItem $searchFolder -filter *$match* -Recurse:$recurse

        $files |
            Sort-Object -Descending -Property { $_.FullName } |
            % {
                Write-Verbose "Renamed $_"
                $newName = $_.name -replace $match, $replacement
                Rename-Item $_.FullName -newname $newName -force
            }       
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Warning "Path not found: $searchFolder"
    }
}
```

Note that one change from the answer is that above recurses folder only in specified folders, not in root. If you don't want that then just set `$recurse = true`.

Comment: @BrokenHeart Any reason you want to [change my edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23103932/revisions)?

Comment: @Antony No reason just to make it much better.